# Handling event from main form in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I am trying to execute code in a UserControl when an even from the main form is raised.

The Form code:

```cs
public partial class mainForm : Form {
    ...

    public event EventHandler listBoxIndexChanged;

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listBoxIndexChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Important to mention here is that the actual form's `Name` is also `mainForm`, just like the classname.

The UserControl code:

```cs
public partial class userControl1 : UserControl {
    public userControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainForm.listBoxIndexChanged += mainForm_listBox1_IndexChanged;
    }

    private void mainForm_listBox1_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // my code
    }
}
```

This code is throwing the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'mainForm.listBoxIndexChanged'`. I'm sure it's something obvious, but what could I be doing wrong?

WinForms .NET Framework 4.8, VS 2019.

Comment: Where is the `mainForm` **instance** coming from? It looks like this object has the same name as the Form class... How does your UC know about a `mainForm`?

Comment: The form object does indeed have the same name as the class. Was this a mistake? It makes sense, now that you mention it. I suppose my UC does not know of `mainForm`'s existence. How should I go about it?

Comment: HOW does your UC know of the existence of a `mainForm` class? Where did you get that **Instance** from? How does the UC know that a Form **Instance** has a public event? Why does your UC care about a specific child Control of this Form? Or does it care about some values? Maybe you have a design flaw...

Comment: The dependency is better to be reverse. Create a public method like `public void DoSomething(){/*my code*/}` in your user control. Then in the form, handle an event in the form and call `DoSomething` method on instance of the user control.

Comment: @Jimi Please just explain what I'm doing wrong instead of asking these questions. I do not know the answer. I'm a complete amateur and you're giving me anxiety with these questions that I don't even understand half the words of. I just want to change the `Visible` property of certain controls in my `UserControl` depending on 2 ListBoxes `SelectedIndex` when one of the ListBox's `SelectedIndex` changes.

Comment: I don't see how asking for clarifications about the code you wrote could produce *anxiety*. Anyway, see what Reza Aghaei suggested: make your UC expose a public method that is called when one or more other Controls change *status*, in a way or another. -- I won't talk about DataBindings, I'm not sure what *side-effects* that may have :)

Comment: I am unable to reference the ListBoxes' `SelectedIndex` in my UserControl's class. I need to be able to do that to execute my code. I have attempted setting `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` (`Form1` being the new name of `mainForm`) in my method. This returns `null` for `frm1.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this runs is that MainForm is created first and then creates an instance of your UserControl inside the MainForm. So, MainForm knows about UserControl but UserControl does not know about MainForm. So when you tell UserControl to use MainForm it doesn't know what MainForm is (no instance). Instead you'll want the MainForm to trigger a method inside the UserControl and pass it the needed information.

In your user control create a method that the MainForm can call:

```
public class UserControl1
{
    public void doSomethingWhenSelectedIndexChanges(int selectedIndex){
        // do stuff inside user control...
    }
}
```

Then in your MainForm call the UserControl method.

```
public class MainForm 
{
    private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        UserControl1.doSomethingWhenSelectedIndexChanges(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

This way the MainForm is telling the UserControl that the ListBox selected index has changed and is passing the selected index to the UserControl.